# How to set column width to my excel sheet using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

```
import Workbook from 'react-xlsx-workbook';
  var obj={};
   obj['id'] = users._id
   obj['sessionCreatedDate'] = users.sessionCreatedDate;
   obj['sessionUpdatedDate'] = users.sessionUpdatedDate;
   data1.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)));
    <Workbook>
     <Workbook.Sheet data={() =>data1}  name="Sheet A">
      <Workbook.Column label="Session Start Date" value="sessionStartDate"/> 
        <Workbook.Column label="Session Start Time" value="sessionStartTime"/> 
         <Workbook.Column label="Session Created Date" value="sessionCreatedDate"/>
       </Workbook.Sheet>
       </Workbook>
```

Comment: Please add details in the questions, it is difficult to understand

Comment: I want to set width for the columns

<Workbook >
  <Workbook.Sheet data={() =>data1}  name="Sheet A">    
       <Workbook.Column label="Session Start Date" value="sessionStartDate"/> 
        <Workbook.Column label="Session Start Time" value="sessionStartTime"/> 
   <Workbook.Column label="Session Created Date" value="sessionCreatedDate"/>
</workbook>

Comment: @SarveshMahajan

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to set some configuration to the table you are creating, take reference from below snippet, or visit https://www.grapecity.com/blogs/add-excel-import-and-export-to-a-react-app:

```
const config = {
    sheetName: 'Sales Data',
    hostClass: ' spreadsheet',
    autoGenerateColumns: false,
    width: 200,
    visible: true,
    resizable: true,
    priceFormatter: '$ #.00',
    chartKey: 1
}

<TablePanel key={config.chartKey} title="Recent Sales">
    <SpreadSheets hostClass={config.hostClass}>
        <Worksheet name={config.sheetName} dataSource={tableData} autoGenerateColumns= 
  {config.autoGenerateColumns}>
            <Column width={50} dataField='id' headerText="ID"></Column>
            <Column width={200} dataField='client' headerText="Client"></Column>
            <Column width={320} dataField='description' headerText="Description"> 
 </Column>
            <Column width={100} dataField='value' headerText="Value" formatter= 
  {config.priceFormatter} resizable="resizable"></Column>
            <Column width={100} dataField='itemCount' headerText="Quantity"></Column>
            <Column width={100} dataField='soldBy' headerText="Sold By"></Column>
            <Column width={100} dataField='country' headerText="Country"></Column>                   
        </Worksheet>
    </SpreadSheets>
</TablePanel>
```

Comment: Sarvesh Mahajan iam using react-xlsx-workbook